# What causes "could not be downloaded due to an error. (498)"

Tags: google-play-store

I purchased an app from Google Play and I uninstalled a while back.  I wanted to get it installed again but when I try to install it I get the error message:

```
"Appname" could not be downloaded due to an error. (498)
```

What does that mean? And what can I do about it?

Answer (score 3):

Solutions (though not the reason behind) are explained e.g. on [Appslova.com](http://appslova.com/android-fix-error-498-in-google-play-store/). Taking a look at them, those are more or less the "Generic Google Play Solutions":

### Method 1

- Go to *Settings→Apps*, Select “All” tab
- Find Google Play Store, open its entry, Clear Data and Cache
- Find Google Service Framework, do the same
- Now restart Google Play Store and try to download/update the app or games

### Method 2

- Open Google Play Store
- Go to *Settings→Accounts*, Choose Account or add new account
- Now try to download or install the app or game

### Method 3

- Go to *Settings→Accounts→Google*, remove your Gmail account
- From *Settings→Apps→All*: Force stop, Clear data and cache for Google Play Store, Google Service Framework and Download Manager (like in method 1)
- Again, go to *Settings→Accounts→Google*, Add your Gmail account
- Restart your android and then accept all the Google terms and setup Google settings
- Run Google Play Store and update or install your app.

---

Some more hints are to be found in [Google's product "forum"](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile/b3d5ZQFLu1I). Reasons here were e.g. **storage full:** Clean up, delete stuff, try again, worked.

Find a bunch more hints, all on the first result page to a [Google search on "google-play error 498"](https://www.google.com/search?q=google-play+error+498&ie=UTF-8) :)